# How can i make a public sub in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, window

I'm trying to make a web service email, but get the error Must have return type. And I don't know how to handle this because I'am new in C#.

Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Email_Service
    {
        public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {   
            public string name;

            public Service1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {

            }

            public Notification(){
               name = "Denmark";
                return name;//I'm just trying this if its work but its not working....
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the return type from the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

> Methods are declared in a class or struct by specifying the access
>   level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as abstract
>   or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any method
>   parameters. These parts together are the signature of the method.

Source - [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

In your case, you want to return a string back, so your method should be defined as :

```
public string Notification(){...}
```

If a method is not returning anything, the return type should be `void`. Regardless, every method needs to have a return type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a C# method to be like a VB "subroutine", simply mark the return type "void".

Otherwise, specify what *type* the function should return.  For example:

`public string Notification() { ...}`

Comment: ooh thanks but im making an email service so I dont know what variable i will use..sorry to ask again for help

Comment: In general, you *must* have a type.  That's the whole *point* of a strongly typed language (like C#, Java and C++)!  SUGGESTION: You can look at the new type "dynamic", introduced in .Net 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx.  BETTER SUGGESTION: Consider having your function return an "abstract class": http://www.dotnetperls.com/abstract